# DNS subdomain ip's

Tags: domain-name-system

For example, I have domain `a.com` with a lot of subdomains on the same ip. I configured DNS A-recors like this:

```
@.a.com. A 1.1.1.1
*.a.com. A 1.1.1.1
```

So, `a.com` and a lot of subdomains are delegated to ip `1.1.1.1`. That's ok.

But I have another server (ip `2.2.2.2`), it will serve static files (css, images, etc) for `a.com`. I want to use this server as `media.a.com` domain. Is it ok to add 3rd line to my DNS like this?

```
@.a.com. A 1.1.1.1
*.a.com. A 1.1.1.1
media.a.com. A 2.2.2.2
```

Will it work properly? Can it cause some DNS problems?

Comment: `@.a.com.` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MadHatter good point. I suppose if it parses at all, it would be interpreted the same as `a.com.` or `@`, in which case it would be better to use the shorter and more correct notation.

Comment: No, assuming the zone is `a.com`, I suspect it would be parsed as `a.com.a.com.`, which is probably not what the OP wants, or worse, `a.com..a.com`, which is nonsensical.

Comment: @MadHatter it's just example, I use short notation `@`, `*` and `media`

Comment: @MadHatter And yes, `a.com` would be parsed as `a.com.a.com` but `a.com.` (with dot in the end) would be parsed correctly.

Comment: Antonio: I agree with those points, but neither are what I was making.  My point was that `@.a.com` is nonsensical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the configuration in your question, the domains will resolve the way one would expect them to. The `*` record is only used when no other record matches.

There are some caveats though. You'll have a challenge, if you ever need a subdomain not to resolve. Imagine at some point, you want to use this domain in a DNS search configuration. If there was a `*` in the zone, then every nonexistent domain would still resolve using the search, that's going to break stuff.

I was facing that exact problem myself and decided to use a subdomain for the search. That works fine for some OS, but eventually I found that Mac OS X when told to use the subdomain for search would also search in the domain above the one it was told to use, so it still got into trouble with the `*` record.

Now the real challenge with the `*` record is, that once you started using it, you'll probably not be keeping track of all the subdomains, which you rely on being resolved using the `*` record. This means that if at any point in the future you decide to drop the `*` record and switch to explicitly listing all the needed subdomains inside the zone file, you may not have that list of subdomains. This is the best argument I have for not using a `*` record in the first place.

Comment: I have more than 1k subdomains, so using `*` is the best solution. When someone tries to hit unexistent subdomain, I'll just return error or redirect header.